# Is it possible to check time being taken by a method call in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot service class, let's say that I am making a method call `processEvent()`.
The method `processEvent()` might be doing N number of things including making REST calls to other services.

How to check the time being taken by the method in parallel and if it crosses the threshold, then do something else e.g. throw exception ?

```
class EventService {  

    public void processEvent(ServiceContext context, Event event) {     

      // Field a time checker here for the below method.  
      processEvent(event);  
    }  
    public void processEvent(Event event) {  
      // this method does many things.  
    }  
}
```

Can this be achieved using [CompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) ? If yes, Please give an example!

**EDIT:**
The following code works but I have one query:

```
public void processEvent(ServiceContext context, Event event) {  

LOGGER.debug("Timestamp before submitting task = {}", System.currentTimeMillis());  

  Future<EventResponse> future = executor.submit(() -> {  
    LOGGER.debug("Timestamp before invoking = {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
    EventResponse eventResponse = processEvent(event);  
    LOGGER.debug("Timestamp after invoking = {}", System.currentTimeMillis());  
    return eventResponse;  
  });  

  try {
    LOGGER.debug("Thread sleep starts at = {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    LOGGER.debug("Thread sleep ended at = {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    LOGGER.debug("Going to print stack trace....");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }  

  if (!future.isDone()) {
    future.cancel(true);
    LOGGER.debug("task executor cancelled at = {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
  } else {
    EventResponse response = future.get();
    LOGGER.debug("Received Event ID = {}", response.getEventDetailsList().get(0).getEventID());
    return response;
  }  

  LOGGER.debug("Going to return error response at = {}", System.currentTimeMillis());  
  throw new Exception("Message");  
}
```

**I am getting the below logs:**

*Timestamp before submitting task = 1579005638324

Thread sleep starts at = 1579005638326

Timestamp before invoking = 1579005638326

Thread sleep ended at = 1579005638526

task executor cancelled at = 1579005638527

Going to return error response at = 1579005638527

Timestamp after invoking = 1579005645228*

**How "Timestamp after invoking" is logged after "task executor cancelled at" ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to submit the task, then sleep for a certain amount of time, then check if the task is completed and interrupt it, if it's still working. However, you can't just kill the task, you'll have to periodically check for the interrupted flag inside the task itself. The code would be something like:

```
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

// ...

Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {

  doOneThing();

  if(Thread.interrupted()) {
    return;
  }

  doAnotherThing();

  if(Thread.interrupted()) {
    return;
  }

  // etc.
});

Thread.sleep(10000);

if (!future.isDone()) {
  future.cancel(true);
}
```

Comment: I updated my question by taking your code reference. Please answer!

Comment: @mukund it's not clear from your code if you are checking for `Thread.interrupted()` inside the `processEvent` method. Calling `future.cancel(true)` doesn't immediately kill your task - it just marks the thread as interrupted. Inside your running task, you should periodically check for `interrupted` flag and return if the flag is set.

Comment: Ohh Thanks. I was in view that `future.cancel(true)` kills the task. But when you say periodically check for interrupted flat, how can I determine the places and how many times I should check this? Can I simply check once before `return eventResponse;` ?

Comment: If you check before return, this will be already after all the work is done, so it won’t have any effect. How and when to check for interruption is dependent on the structure of your code. If there’s multiple steps, you could check after each one. If there’s a loop, you could check on each iteration, etc.

Comment: Also, if the heavy method is calling REST services, and you want to make sure it won’t hang indefinitely, probably you could just set some sane timeouts for your requests instead of interrupting the method externally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of a standard [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). The latter will cancel the submission of the former if it's still running.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = ...;

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor watcher = ...;

Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> { ...  })

watcher.schedule(() -> future.cancel(true), THRESHOLD_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The `future.cancel(true)` will be a no-op if it completed. For this though, you should be aware of how to handle cross-thread communiccation and cancellation. `cancel(true)` says *"Either prevent this from running entirely, or, if it is running, interrupt the thread indicating we need to stop execution entirely and immediately"*

From there your `Runnable` should handle interruption as a stop condition:

```
executor.submit(()-> {
   // do something
   if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // clean up and exit early
   }
   // continue doing something
});
```